# Dismiss UISearchBar keyboard without affecting cancel button

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uikeyboard

I am trying to reproduce the functionality that can be seen in the contacts app on the iphone. I have a UISearchBar that dismisses the keyboard when the search button is clicked. This however deactivitates the cancel button and it requires 2 touches to activate. On the contacts app it is not deactivated when the search button is clicked and the keyboard is dismissed.

So what I am asking is how to dismiss the keyboard without deactivating the cancel button on the uiSearchBar?

I have tried

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

//Some other code

//I have Tried
//Attempt 1
 self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
//Attempt 2
  self.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
//Attempt 3
  var textFieldInsideSearchBar = searchBar.valueForKey("searchField") as? UITextField
  textFieldInsideSearchBar.endEditing(true)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegate method parses you **searchBar**, so you do not have to use **self.searchBar**, that might be one of the issues. I usually use logic from your *"Attempt 2"*.

You can try to implement this:

```
func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
```

And call `searchBar.resignFirstResponder()`.

If it does not work, then try to implement this method and return **true**:

```
func searchBarShouldEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool
```

If you are using UISearchBar in combination with UISearchDisplatController, then try this method on **searchDisplayController**:

```
func setActive(_ visible: Bool, animated animated;: Bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

It quite bit tricky.
Try,

```
[self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
[(UIButton *)[self.searchBar valueForKey:@"_cancelButton"] setEnabled:YES];
```